# C++ for loop causing memory leak?

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector, memory-leaks, iterator

I've got a game server made in C++ and I recently noticed that the memory count is continuously growing.

I start my server up, and then I open task manager (Windows 7) and look at the memory for it. The memory is fine for about 20 seconds but after that it goes up and doesn't stop.

I've narrowed down the code that's doing this:

```
for(std::vector<Door>::iterator door = myMap()->doors.begin(); door != myMap()->doors.end(); ++door){

}
```

I don't even need any code inside of the for loop, it's this code that has a memory leak. But what could be the memory leak? It's a standard loop going through a vector object.

The code above is run in a function call that gets updated through a while loop on a separate thread. If I comment that code out the memory count is fine.

EDIT:
myMap() definition:

```
Map* Player::myMap(){
    if(mapList == NULL){
        //cout << "mapList was NULL" << endl;
        return NULL;
    }

    //std::map<std::string, Map*> &myMapList = *mapList;

    //cout << "getting my map: " << (*mapList)["f1"]->blocks.at(0).x << endl;
    return (*mapList)[strdup(room.c_str())];
}
```

Please let me know if I need to provide any additional code.

Comment: What is `myMap()` doing? What are the things _in_ `myMap()` doing?

Comment: Show the definition of `myMap`, and any other code it calls into.

Comment: I'm betting the `myMap()` function has a `new` inside it :D

Comment: In addition to the speculation that your `myMap` function is allocating memory without deallocating memory, there are other potential issues.  If `myMap()` returns a new instance, you are messing up the iteration due to using different `door` vectors.

Comment: Okay I've added the definition for myMap().
Basically mapList is a map (don't get confused by the names, "Map" refers to a level on the game server) that contains both a string and a pointer to a Map object.

It's basically used so I can retrieve a Map object via a string name inside the myMap() function definition.

IE If I wanted to get the object for the Map called "FirstLevel" in the mapList.

Comment: Paul, is that it? Do you have a better solution?

Comment: @RanShorowitz Before giving an answer, is there a potential of returning a different map object while you're looping?  If so, your loop has bigger problems than fixing strdup (see my original comment).  Anyway, why are you using `strdup` in a C++ program anyway?  That should have gone the way of the dodo bird w.r.t C++.

Comment: Why is the call to `strdup` even needed? No need to duplicate the string as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you provided the definition of `myMap`, I can tell you that the memory leaks come from the call to `strdup`. The pointer returned by this function should be freed (by a call to `free`), since it calls `malloc`.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think the problem is inside your for loop, since I can run the following without any leaks that I can detect:

```
#include <vector>

int main(){
    std::vector<int> my_vector;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        my_vector.push_back(i);
    for(;;)
        for(std::vector<int>::iterator it = my_vector.begin(); it != my_vector.end(); ++it){}
}
```

of course, depending on your compiler, your mileage may vary. But I'd suspect it was the myMap call instead, since that's creates its own function scope that will become unreachable, and would leak any leftover memory.

---

Edit: Based on your myMap implementation, it looks like strdup is the culprit. It will allocate and return a pointer to a new character array every time, so every call to myMap produces a new copy of the same string.

Comment: How can you know without seeing `Door`'s and `myMap()`'s implementation? The problem might well be part of the for loop.

Comment: `I can run the following without any leaks that I can detect:` Consider this: `Instance* myMap() { return new Instance; }`  Now do you see how the loop can cause a memory leak?

Comment: My point was that the problem was not with his for loop code, but rather his implementation of myMap. Thank you for the input though.